# Java run jar from another jar with passing arguments

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have generated run1.jar:

```
   package runner;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    public class Run1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            System.out.println(i);

            try {
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("1.txt", "UTF-8");
                writer.println(i);
                writer.println(i);
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do something
            }

        }
    }
```

Also I have generated run2.jar:

```
package runner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Run2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "C:\\test2\\run1.jar", "1");
        pb.directory(new File("C:\\"));
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I have ran with this command **java -jar run2.jar 1** and work it.
Expecting result is running with this command: **java -jar run2.jar** who doesn't work.

How can I run run2.jar with passing parameters from inside main method in run2.jar?

Error is:

```
C:\test2>java -jar run2.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at runner.Run1.main(Run1.java:9)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks! specifically: **does not work** isnt a problem description we could work with.

Comment: you forgot  a \ after `test2`.

Comment: is there any error message or stack trace with more information on why it doesn't work?

Comment: It might problem for jar directory path, try . /jar_path/. Jar

Comment: This is  message error returned after I ran  java -jar run2.jar: https://pastebin.com/jL7xnF7e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are , below two different example which answer to your question

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:\\...\\Run1.jar 1");
        proc.waitFor();

        //2 inputstream for the result and for the errors in subprogram     
        InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();

        byte b[]=new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(b,0,b.length);
        System.out.println(new String(b));

        byte c[]=new byte[err.available()];
        err.read(c,0,c.length);
        System.out.println(new String(c));

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "C:\\...\\Run1.jar", "1");
        Process proc2 = pb.start();
        proc2.waitFor();

        InputStream in2 = proc2.getInputStream();
        InputStream err2 = proc2.getErrorStream();

        byte b2[]=new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(b,0,b.length);
        System.out.println(new String(b));

        byte c2[]=new byte[err.available()];
        err.read(c,0,c.length);
        System.out.println(new String(c));
```

Output from IDE (Eclipse)

[image]

Output from command line :

[image]

**Note:** the "ok" is a my System.out.println i put in Run1.jar ( i saved the files jar with capital letter , but you can use yours names )

Comment: you're welcome , if i can suggest to you i would use processbuilder(easier use)  instead of Runtime , in addition from java 8 if i'm correct you can use waitfor method with parameters (timeout) and it can be useful in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

The error I have added to your question is relative to a missing argument: `args[0]`, line 9 throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The argument "1" isn't passed to run1.jar

The exception stack shows a jar-in-jar loader usage, why?

Build the jars with Oracle command line utilities or ANT and test again.

Comment: How can I build this jar by command line? I have build from command line but didn't success with: jar cf run1.jar Run1.java. After compiled and running output this error: no main manifest attribute, in run1.jar

Comment: A jar contains byte code not source! try Run1.class